# SwiftUI: Reset State When Drag Operation Ends Without Drop

Tags: swiftui

I'm working with SwiftUI's drag and drop API and facing a challenge in managing the state of a draggable view. My goal is to change the view's color and maintain a state flag (isDragging) when a drag operation starts and then reset that state when the drag operation ends, regardless of whether it ends in a successful drop or not. However, I'm encountering an issue where the state isn't reset if the user starts a drag (long press) on the view but then releases their finger without moving enough to initiate the drag action. This results in the view's color and the isDragging state not reverting back to their initial states.

Here's a simplified version of my SwiftUI view structure:

```
struct DropTest: View {
    @State var isDragging = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(isDragging ? Color.gray : Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            .onDrag {
                self.isDragging = true
                return NSItemProvider(object: String("Drag initiated") as NSString)
            }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.green.opacity(0.01))
    .onDrop(of: [.plainText], delegate: DropViewDelegate3(isDragging: $isDragging))
}
}

struct DropViewDelegate3: DropDelegate {
@Binding var isDragging: Bool

func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    self.isDragging = false
    return true
}

func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
    self.isDragging = false
}
}
```

The problem occurs when a user taps and holds on the Rectangle, causing it to change color as expected due to the isDragging state changing to true. If the user then releases their finger without moving it (thus not initiating a "real" drag action), the Rectangle remains gray, and isDragging stays true, which is not the intended behavior. I want isDragging to reset to false, and the Rectangle to revert to blue when the drag does not proceed to an actual drag-and-drop operation.

**What I've Tried**
I've experimented with adding .gesture modifiers to detect taps or changes in drag state, but it either interferes with the onDrag functionality or doesn't catch the specific scenario of releasing the finger without dragging. Notably, in my app, employing gestures like LongPressGesture or DragGesture with a minimumDistance of 0 adversely affects the functionality of a ScrollView. These gestures interfere with the scroll behavior, making them impractical solutions for my use case.

**Question**
How can I detect the end of a drag action that doesn't result in a drop within SwiftUI, so I can reset the isDragging state and view color appropriately? Is there a way to hook into a lower-level event or use a different approach within SwiftUI to achieve this behavior?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!